# PowerShell inline If (IIf)

Tags: powershell, iif

How do I create an a statement with an inline If (IIf, see also: [Immediate if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf) or [ternary If](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F)) in PowerShell?

<strike>If you also think that this should be a native PowerShell function, please vote this up: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1497806/iif-statement-if-shorthand</strike>

### Update (7 October 2019)

The [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1497806/iif-statement-if-shorthand) is retired, but the good news is that [support for a ternary operator in PowerShell (Core) language](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/10367) appears to be on its way...

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell’s native way:

```
"The condition is " + (&{If($Condition) {"True"} Else {"False"}}) + "."
```

But as this adds a lot of parenthesis and brackets to your syntax, you might consider the following (probably one of the smallest existing) CmdLet:

```
Function IIf($If, $Right, $Wrong) {If ($If) {$Right} Else {$Wrong}}
```

Which will simplify your command to:

```
"The condition is " + (IIf $Condition "True" "False") + "."
```

---

*Added 2014-09-19:*

I have been using the `IIf` cmdlet now for a while, and I still think it will make syntaxes more readable in a lot of cases, but as I agree with Jason’s note about the unwanted side effect that both possible values will be evaluated even obviously only one value is used, I have changed the `IIf` cmdlet a bit:

```
Function IIf($If, $IfTrue, $IfFalse) {
    If ($If) {If ($IfTrue -is "ScriptBlock") {&$IfTrue} Else {$IfTrue}}
    Else {If ($IfFalse -is "ScriptBlock") {&$IfFalse} Else {$IfFalse}}
}
```

Now you *might* add a ScriptBlock (surrounded by `{}`'s) instead of an object which will not be evaluated if it is not required as shown in this example:

```
IIf $a {1/$a} NaN
```

Or placed inline:

```
"The multiplicative inverse of $a is $(IIf $a {1/$a} NaN)."
```

In case `$a` has a value other than zero, the multiplicative inverse is returned; otherwise, it will return `NaN` (where the `{1/$a}` is not evaluated).

Another nice example where it will make a quiet ambiguous syntax a lot simpler (especially in case you want to place it inline) is where you want to run a method on an object which could potentially be `$Null`.

The native ‘`If`’ way to do this, would be something like this:

```
If ($Object) {$a = $Object.Method()} Else {$a = $null}
```

(Note that the `Else` part is often required in e.g. loops where you will need to reset `$a`.)

With the `IIf` cmdlet it will look like this:

```
$a = IIf $Object {$Object.Method()}
```

(Note that if the `$Object` is `$Null`, `$a` will automatically be set to `$Null` if no `$IfFalse` value is supplied.)

---

*Added 2014-09-19:*

Minor change to the `IIf` cmdlet which now sets the current object ([`$_`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847768.aspx) or [`$PSItem`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847768.aspx)):

```
Function IIf($If, $Then, $Else) {
    If ($If -IsNot "Boolean") {$_ = $If}
    If ($If) {If ($Then -is "ScriptBlock") {&$Then} Else {$Then}}
    Else {If ($Else -is "ScriptBlock") {&$Else} Else {$Else}}
}
```

This means you can simplify a statement (the PowerShell way) with a method on an object that could potentially be `$Null`.

The general syntax for this will now be `$a = IIf $Object {$_.Method()}`. A more common example will look something like:

```
$VolatileEnvironment = Get-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "HKCU:\Volatile Environment"
$UserName = IIf $VolatileEnvironment {$_.GetValue("UserName")}
```

Note that the command `$VolatileEnvironment.GetValue("UserName")` will normally result in an **"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."** error if the concerned registry (`HKCU:\Volatile Environment`) doesn’t exist; where the command  `IIf $VolatileEnvironment {$_.GetValue("UserName")}` will just return `$Null`.

If the `$If` parameter is a condition (something like `$Number -lt 5`) or forced to a condition (with the `[Bool]` type), the `IIf` cmdlet won't overrule the current object, e.g.:

```
$RegistryKeys | ForEach {
    $UserName = IIf ($Number -lt 5) {$_.GetValue("UserName")}
}
```

Or:

```
$RegistryKeys | ForEach {
    $UserName = IIf [Bool]$VolatileEnvironment {$_.OtherMethod()}
}
```

---

*Added 2020-03-20:*

[**Using the ternary operator syntax**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7#using-the-ternary-operator-syntax)

PowerShell 7.0 introduced a new syntax using the ternary operator. It follows the C# ternary operator syntax:

> The ternary operator behaves like the simplified `if-else` statement.
>   The `<condition>` expression is evaluated and the result is converted
>   to a boolean to determine which branch should be evaluated next:
>
> The `<if-true>` expression is executed if the `<condition>` expression is true 
>   The `<if-false>` expression is executed if the `<condition>` expression is false

**Example**:

```
"The multiplicative inverse of $a is $($a ? (& {1/$a}) : 'NaN')."
```

Comment: Your first example can be slightly simpler: "The condition is $(If($Condition) {"True"} Else {"False"})."

Comment: The second example is nice if the values have no side effects but it's not good if there are side effects because the side effects will happen on both $Right and $Wrong before entering the IIf function.

Answer (score 68):

**Powershell 7+** allows [ternary operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7#ternary-operator):

```
$price = 150
$text = $price -gt 100 ? 'expensive' : 'cheap'
$text
# output: 
# expensive
```

**Powershell 6** (or older) gives back values that haven't been assigned.

```
$price = 150
$text = if ($price -gt 100) { 'expensive' } else { 'cheap' }
$text
# output:
# expensive
```

Answer (score 37):

```
'The condition is {0}.' -f ('false','true')[$condition]
```

Comment: mjolinor. Clever use of the index operator there (in conjunction with composite formatting).

Comment: Nice.  Inline. One line.  Plus a little what does this code do problem for the interested code reviewer :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way:

```
$condition = $false

"The condition is $(@{$true = "true"; $false = "false"}[$condition])"
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn’t evaluate the condition and therefore returns nothing in cases like `$Condition = "Has Text"` and `$Condition = 10` (which might sometimes desired, but not PowerShell like), therefore I would change it to: `"The condition is $(@("False", "True")[[Bool]$Condition])"`

Comment: You are right, for this specific example. If $condition = 10, you would do it like this: "The condition is $(@{$true = "greater than 50"; $false = "less than 50"}[$condition -gt 50])"

Answer (score 2):

From blog post *[DIY: Ternary operator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/29/diy-ternary-operator/)*:

```
Relevant code:
# —————————————————————————
# Name:   Invoke-Ternary
# Alias:  ?:
# Author: Karl Prosser
# Desc:   Similar to the C# ? : operator e.g. 
#            _name = (value != null) ? String.Empty : value;
# Usage:  1..10 | ?: {$_ -gt 5} {“Greater than 5;$_} {“Not greater than 5”;$_}
# —————————————————————————
set-alias ?: Invoke-Ternary -Option AllScope -Description “PSCX filter alias”
filter Invoke-Ternary ([scriptblock]$decider, [scriptblock]$ifTrue, [scriptblock]$ifFalse) 
{
   if (&$decider) { 
      &$ifTrue
   } else { 
      &$ifFalse 
   }
}
```

And then you can use that like this:

```
$total = ($quantity * $price ) * (?:  {$quantity -le 10} {.9} {.75})
```

This is the closest variant I have seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Compare-InlineIf  
{  
[CmdletBinding()]  
    Param(  
        [Parameter(  
            position=0,  
            Mandatory=$false,  
            ValueFromPipeline=$false  
        )]  
        $Condition,  
        [Parameter(  
            position=1,  
            Mandatory=$false,  
            ValueFromPipeline=$false  
        )]  
        $IfTrue,  
        [Parameter(  
            position=2,  
            Mandatory=$false,  
            ValueFromPipeline=$false  
        )]  
        $IfFalse  
    )  
    Begin{  
        Function Usage  
        {  
            write-host @"  
Syntax  
    Compare-InlineIF [[-Condition] <test>] [[-IfTrue] <String> or <ScriptBlock>]  
 [[-IfFalse] <String> or <ScriptBlock>]  
Inputs  
    None  
    You cannot pipe objects to this cmdlet.  

Outputs  
    Depending on the evaluation of the condition statement, will be either the IfTrue or IfFalse suplied parameter values  
Examples  
   .Example 1: perform Compare-InlineIf :  
    PS C:\>Compare-InlineIf -Condition (6 -gt 5) -IfTrue "yes" -IfFalse "no"  

    yes

   .Example 2: perform IIF :  
    PS C:\>IIF (6 -gt 5) "yes" "no"  

    yes  

   .Example 3: perform IIF :  
    PS C:\>IIF `$object "`$true","`$false"  

    False  

   .Example 4: perform IIF :  
    `$object = Get-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "HKCU:\AppEvents\EventLabels\.Default\"  
    IIf `$object {`$_.GetValue("DispFilename")}  

    @mmres.dll,-5824  
"@  
        }  
    }  
    Process{  
        IF($IfTrue.count -eq 2 -and -not($IfFalse)){  
            $IfFalse = $IfTrue[1]  
            $IfTrue = $IfTrue[0]  
        }elseif($iftrue.count -ge 3 -and -not($IfFalse)){  
            Usage  
            break  
        }  
        If ($Condition -IsNot "Boolean")  
        {  
            $_ = $Condition  
        } else {}  
        If ($Condition)  
        {  
            If ($IfTrue -is "ScriptBlock")  
            {  
                &$IfTrue  
            }  
            Else  
            {  
                $IfTrue  
            }  
        }  
        Else  
        {  
            If ($IfFalse -is "ScriptBlock")  
            {  
                &$IfFalse  
            }  
            Else  
            {  
                $IfFalse  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    End{}  
}  
Set-Alias -Name IIF -Value Compare-InlineIf
```

Comment: This is just a repost/slight improvement of the custom function that was discussed above. Nothing really new other than small piece that determines if two items were passed for the second parameter and nothing for the third, splits it out to both parameters. This makes it act in a way that is consistent with VBA where IIF is common.

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell doesn't have support for inline ifs. You'll have to create your own function (as another answer suggests), or combine if/else statements on a single line (as another answer also suggests).