# PowerShell syntax for something like :? operator?

Tags: powershell, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator

I'm doing a thing where I pick apart an XML document and write the text content of some elements to a file. The basic approach is dirt-simple once I have the XML document loaded: all I do is things like

`$DI_XMLResponse.result.gudid.device.versionModelNumber | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append -NoClobber -Encoding ascii`

but I need to arrange for an empty line to be emitted in the case where the leaf element has no content, or does not exist at all.

I could assign the content to a variable, test whether the variable is null, and and if so make it be an empty string, and then write it out to the file,

`$foo = $DI_XMLResponse.result.gudid.device.versionModelNumber 
if (!$foo) $foo = ''
$foo | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append -NoClobber -Encoding ascii`

but I'm hoping to find some more compact sort of expression. Is there one?

Answer (score 9):

**Update**:

- PowerShell (Core) **7.0** introduced the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false) 
  (`$condition ? $valueIfTrue : $valueIfFalse`) and the [null-coalescing operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-coalescing-operator-) (`$possibleNullValue ?? $valueIfNull` and `$possibleNullValue ??= $valueIfNull`}
- PowerShell (Core) **7.1** introduced the [null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) (`${possibleNullValue}?.Property` and `${possibleNullValue}?[0]`)

  - Note the unfortunate need for `{...}` around the variable name, because - counterintuitively - `?` is currently a legal variable-name character - see [GitHub issue #14025](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14025).

The rest of this answer shows **ways to *emulate* the ternary operator and null-coalescing for *Windows PowerShell*** (as well as for the now obsolete PowerShell (Core) versions *6.x and earlier*):

---

Unfortunately, ***Windows PowerShell* does *not* have a [ternary [conditional] operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) (e.g.,

`$condition ? $valueIfTrue : $valueIfFalse`) or a [null-coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) (e.g.,

`$possibleNullValue ?? $valueIfNull`)**.

In your specific case, **you're looking for the *null-coalescing* operator**, and there are - suboptimal - **workarounds**:

---

**Define a custom function**, as shown in [Ryan Schlueter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52899938/45375) for the *ternary* operator.

For the *null-coalescing* operator it could be something like:

```bash
function ?? ($PossiblyNull, $ValueIfNull) { 
  if ($null -eq $PossiblyNull) { $ValueIfNull } else { $PossiblyNull }
}
```

Applied to your code:

```bash
?? $DI_XMLResponse.result.gudid.device.versionModelNumber '' |
  Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append -NoClobber -Encoding ascii
```

The **down-sides of custom functions** are:

- You need to **include or import them** into in every piece of code you want to use them in.
- If you choose familiar names such a `?:` and `??`, the **placement of operands can get confusing**, because you must (invariably) place them differently in PowerShell, given the implementation as a *function* (e.g.,
  `a ?? b` in C# vs. `?? $a $b` in PowerShell).

---

Use a **helper array with implicit Boolean-to-integer conversion**:

```bash
$foo = $DI_XMLResponse.result.gudid.device.versionModelNumber
($foo, '')[$null -eq $foo] | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append -NoClobber -Encoding ascii
```

- `($foo, '')` is an array containing the two possible values to output.
- `$null -eq $foo` is conditional that evaluates to `$False`, if `$foo` is `$null`, and `$False` otherwise

  - Note that `$null` is deliberate placed on the LHS, because on the RHS it would perform a different test if `$foo` happened to be *array*-valued.
- In the context of *array indexing*, an `[int]` value is expected, so `$True` is automatically converted to `1`, whereas `$False` results in `0`.
- The net result is that if `$foo` is `$null`, `''` is output; otherwise, `$foo` is used as-is.

The **down-sides** of this approach:

- **No short-circuiting logic** is applied; i.e., both array elements are *unconditionally* evaluated before the appropriate element is chosen.
- If **null-coalescing** is all that is needed, you must store the value to test for `$null` in a variable first; e.g., to emulate
  `(Get-Foo Bar) ?? '(none)'`
  you must first save the output from `Get-Foo Bar` in an **auxiliary variable**, so that you can write:
  `$aux = Get-Foo Bar; ($aux, '(none)')[$null -eq $aux]`

Answer (score 1):

This is my go to is adding a small cmdlet. [PowerShell Inline If (IIf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682507/powershell-inline-if-iif)

```
$foo = $null;
Write-Host (IIf $foo "True" "False")

Function IIf($If, $Right, $Wrong) {If ($If) {$Right} Else {$Wrong}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assignments can be evaluated as expressions. What this means for you is you can transform what you've done if all you care about is brevity over readability:

```
if (-not ($foo = $xml. ...)) {
    $foo = ''
}
```