# Powershell error when trying to generate CSV (empty values)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a script to return a CSV list of all the .exe and .dll stored in a folder with their name, size and version.

To do so, I'm using this script :

```
$path = 'C:\MyFolder'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path * -include *.dll,*.exe -Recurse |
Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
              @{Name = 'Size'; Expression = {$_.Length}},
              @{Name = 'Modified'; Expression = {$_.LastWriteTime}},
              @{Name = 'ProductVersion'; Expression = {($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion.ToString())}} 

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\softwareVersions.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Unfortunately, some of my files don't have any version, so on the screen, I just see an empty value under the "ProductVersion" column, but because of that, I can't generate my CSV, I get the error :

```
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null
```

I tried to replace the concerned line (the one with the version I guess) to try to replace the Version by "Not available" if this information is not found, but I'm a beginner in Powershell code, and it doesn't work... Here's what I tried :

```
@{Name = 'ProductVersion'; Expression = if(!!$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion) {'Not available'}else{($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion)}}
```

I hope that you have all the needed information, as I'm here to ask your help, code masters :-)

Thanks in advance for your time and your answer!!

Jerome

Comment: It is not because your `ProductVersion` property is empty but because you'r not assigning  the result to `$result `. In other words: `$result  =  Get-ChildItem -Path $path * -include *.dll,*.exe -Recurse |
Select-Object ...`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @iRon! You were true, it works now! For my understanding, could you tell me how could I replace an empty version with "Not available" as like I tried in this code :

'@{Name = 'ProductVersion'; Expression = if(!!$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion) {'Not available'}else{($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion)}}'

Thanks in advance

Comment: For replacing the empty value with something else you might use an [Inline If](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25682508/1701026)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) and [pwndsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13699968/pwndsh) are correct.

You need to capture the result of the whole code block starting with `Get-ChildItem` in a variable called `$result`. Then you can either show whatever is in there on screen or save it as proper CSV file.

Also, when testing for `Not Something`, you can either use **one** exclamation mark `!` or the `-not` operator. When you double this you are negating the negation, so in this case I would suggest simply testing for `if Something, do this, else do that`, to stop the confusion:

```
$path   = 'C:\MyFolder'
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*' -Include '*.dll','*.exe' -Recurse |
          Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                        @{Name = 'Size'; Expression = {$_.Length}},
                        @{Name = 'Modified'; Expression = {$_.LastWriteTime}},
                        @{Name = 'ProductVersion'; Expression = {
                            if ($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion) {
                                $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion.ToString()
                            }
                            else {
                                'Not available'
                            }}
                       }

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\softwareVersions.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost done it by your own ;)

Just remove one exclamation mark (!) in your expression.
You entered two.

"!!" will negate it twice which is like not negating it.

Comment: Hello @pwndsh, thank you for your answer. I just tried my script and remove one of the "!" but then my ProductVersion column remains empty, no matter of the availability of the version or not... I don't see any "Not available" or neither any version. i don't get any error neither! Any idea? thank you

Comment: That probably means there is a version available, even if it's just nonsense.

Please try '-notin' in your expression: 
if ($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -notin $null, '') { 'Not available' } else { $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersio }

Comment: PS (sorry 5 minutes ..):

That probably means there is a version available, even if it's just nonsense.

Please try '-notin' in your expression (hint: '' are two single quotes): 
if ($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -notin $null, '') { 'Not available' } else { $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion }

Just for information:
The property you're trying to gather is a .NET class (VERSION).
Therefore, the value is not immediately empty or NULL when there is no version defined.
Every version is by default '0.0.0.0'.