# How to translate -WhatIf into a switch of a native command

Tags: powershell

My advanced script (with `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]` attribute) calls a native command. That native command supports a switch that causes it to run in "dry run" mode, i.e., just outputting what would be copied or deleted without actually doing any copying/deleting.

Sample code of the script:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
param ()
gsutil -m rsync -r -n something gs://something
```

Here the `-n` switch turns on the dry run mode.

**How can I specify this switch based on whether `WhatIf` switch was passed to my script?**

According to [this official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.3#trust-but-verify), other cmdlets should inherit `-WhatIf` values automatically, but still it is suggested to explicitly pass the value to the cmdlets: `-WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference`. But in the call to a native command, I suppose, this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the disadvantages of using native commands vs. cmdlets. I guess that you could do something with an [inline if](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25682507/1701026) but for clarity, I would just do two full statements in an `if/else`, like: `if (WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference) { gsutil -n ... } else { gsutil ... }`

Comment: If ```Start-Process``` is an option, you could append ```-n``` to the ```-ArgumentList``` values depending on whether your cmdlet was called with ```-WhatIf```. That would let you separate the logic of building arguments from the step to actually invoke the native command…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, you could check the [`$WhatIfPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#whatifpreference) preference variable, which will be `$true`, when your script has been called with `-WhatIf` argument.

```sh
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
param ()

$dryMode = @( if( $WhatIfPreference ) { '-n' } )
gsutil -m rsync -r @dryMode something gs://something
```

To avoid duplicating the `gsutil` commandline, I've used [argument splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3). To support splatting, `$dryMode` must be an array, which is enforced through the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#array-subexpression-operator--) `@(…)`. If `$WhatIfPreference` is `$true`, the array will consist of a single string with the value `-n`. Otherwise the array will be empty and splatting an empty array doesn't insert anything into the commandline (not even a space).

Using **PowerShell 7+**, a cleaner syntax using [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.3#using-the-ternary-operator-syntax) is possible:

```sh
$dryMode = $WhatIfPreference ? @('-n') : @()
gsutil -m rsync -r @dryMode something gs://something
```